# Wireless Mouse not being recognized on Windows 10 after Update to May 2020 Build (Version 2004)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, logitech-mouse

I have an Acer Aspire Laptop dual-booted and running Windows 10 version 2004, and Ubuntu 20.04. Since the update (windows update), my wireless mouse (a Logitech m235) has stopped working except for the scroll wheel, and also the mouse works just as fine on my Ubuntu system, and on an another Windows Machine (Windows 10 1903 version). I have tried forcefully installing drivers, disabling etc etc., but without any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would rollback to the previous version of Windows

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound It did the trick!

Comment: Staying on 1909 is not a permanent solution, but eventually Logitech will release an updated drive, which likely will solve the issue on 2004.

Comment: I also had the same issue. After 2004 update, everything connected to USB ports were not detected. Each time i had to reinstall the USB 3.0 drivers via device manager to make them detected.